# Two disjoint closed sets may have zero distance between

Tags: general-topology

It is known that there exist two disjoint closed sets $A$ and $B$ such that $d(A, B) = 0$. For instance, one can take $A = \mathbb{N}, B =\{ n + 1/(2n): n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

However, I am wondering where my following reasoning is wrong:

Suppose $A, B \subset X$ are two disjoint closed subsets and $d(A, B) = 0$. This suggests that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists a\in A, b \in B \ni d(a, b) < \epsilon$, whence one can construct a Cauchy sequence $a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, \cdots $. By assuming $X$ to be complete, one can conclude there is $x\in \bar{A} \cap \bar{B} = A \cap B$, contradicting the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

Hope someone can point out my fallacy. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you intended to construct $a_i, b_i$ so that $d(a_i, b_i) \le \frac{1}{i}$ or similar. There's no reason the sequence should be Cauchy, and for your choice of $A$ and $B$ they aren't.

Comment: so you considered $X = \mathbb{R}$?   In your example, $A\cap B = \emptyset$ ?  Also you can see that for very small $\epsilon$,  one should pick $n$ large such that $1/(2n) < \epsilon$ so that $a = n$, $b = n + 1/(2n)$ are within distance $< \epsilon$

Comment: Yes, I think @QiaochuYuan got the point. I indeed intended to construct a Cauchy sequence by $d( a_k, b_k) < 1/k$, but there is no reason I could believe this would control the distance between $b_k$ and $a_{k+1}$ or so.

Comment: You want $\subset$ not $\in$

Comment: @zhw. Exactly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that you know is that the sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are *cofinal*, meaning that $d(a_n,b_n) \to 0$. That's all. For example, consider the real axis and the hyperbola $xy=1$. Your logic would yield two sequences, say $(n,0)$ and $(n,1/n)$ that both diverge to $\infty$ but are cofinal.

Comment: I appreciate your example. Big thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Cauchy condition is not simply that there exists a *single pair* of elements that are closer than $\epsilon$, but that beyond some index, *all pairs* of elements are closer than $\epsilon$.

In particular, you've done nothing to control the size of $d(a_n, a_{n+1})$, or even the consecutive terms $d(b_n, a_{n+1})$!

Comment: Big thanks! I have taken it for granted that by demanding $d(a_k, b_k) < 1/k$ one can control the following sequence as well. Apparently it doesn't work that way.